# Ruby on Rails Render a Partial with new data from AJAX call in a from

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

so I am profoundly stuck and get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x007f98a9f36418>:0x007f989026e500>)
```

Here is what my code is trying to do. The user goes to the "new" page and there is a form with a few drop downs in it. The user selects an item in a drop down. This triggers an ajax call to the server to get data to populate the next dropdown, which is contained in a partial. Here is the beginning of the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @residency,:class=>"col s12" do |f| %>
  <div id= "site_selection" class="row">
    <% unless edit_view @residency %>
      <h5> Basics </h5>
      <h4>Step 1: Search for your intervew site</h4>
        <select id="specialty-selected"><%=  options_for_select(@specialty_list, "specialty") %></select>
        <select id="city-selected"><%= options_for_select(@city_list, "city")%></select>
    <%end%>
  </div>
     <!-- Searched Residency Dropdown goes here Start-->
  <div id="residency-site-dropdown">
    <%= render :partial=>"select_residency_site", locals:{:f=>f} %>
  </div>
      <!-- Searched Residency Dropdown goes here END-->
```

Here is the partial:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:residency_site_id, @valid_residencies, :id, :name_for_dropdown, {prompt: true, required: true}) %>
```

My controller handles this with the following:

```
@valid_residencies = ResidencySite.where(query)
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {render "form_filter"}
```

_form_filter.js.erb contains the following:

```
$("div#residency-site-dropdown").html("<%= j escape_javascript(render partial: 'select_residency_site', locals:{@valid_residencies=>@valid_residencies, :f=>f } ) %>");
```

Everything works from loading the form which contains the partial, triggering the ajax call, getting the appropriate data from the db. Its just that my _form_filter.js.erb is not working. All I want to do is update this stupid dropdown using the @valid_residencies object.

Help :)

Comment: In your controller, when you call `render "form_filter"` it has no way of knowing what `f` is. You could use `select_tag`, name the input manually, and populate the options.

Comment: What do you mean name the input manually?

Comment: Anyway to tell it what f is?